# How can I bind an event handler to an instance in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dom

I am trying to bind an event to a "method" of a particular instance of a Javascript "class" using jQuery. The requirement is that I in the event handler should be able to use the "this" keyword to refer to the instance I originally bound the event to.

In more detail, say I have a "class" as follows:

```
function Car(owner) {
  this.owner = owner;
}
Car.prototype = {
  drive: function() {
    alert("Driving "+this.owner+"s car!");
  }
}
```

And an instance:

```
var myCar = new Car("Bob");
```

I now want to bind an event to the drive "method" of my car so that when ever I click a button for example the drive "method" is called on the myCar instance of the Car "class".

Up until now I've been using the following function to create a closure that allows me to comfortably access instance members using the "this" keyword in my "methods".

```
function createHandler( obj, method ) {
  return function( event ) {
    return obj[method](event||window.event);
  }
}
```

I've used it as follows:

```
document.getElementById("myButton")
  .addEventListener("click", createHandler(myCar,"drive"));
```

How do I accomplish something like this with JQuery?

I'm specifically asking about associating "this" with a designated instance, the other cruft all around I can handle on my own.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289045/jquery-attach-event-to-method-in-instance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use an anonymous function:

```
$("#myButton").click(function() { myCar.drive(); });
```

Comment: this will work only for one instance. if there multiple instances of Car, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$("#myButton").each(function() {

var $btn = $(this);

    $btn.on('click',function(){

     // Do whatever you want.

    });
});
```

Here you first create a loop to target all #myButton elements (Which is wrong in your example, You should be using Class instead) like:

```
$(".myButton").each(...
```

Then we attach the click event handler to all of them.