# JQuery attach event to method in instance

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code that looks like this....

```
function Finder(id) {
            this.id = id;
            this.input = $("#" + this.id + " :input[type='text']:first")[0];
            $(this.input).bind('keyup'....);



            this.KeyUpHandler = function (e) { ..the event should trigger this.. }
```

this.input = the 1st element of type input found within 'id' which is what I will be referencing. This works fine for what I need.

What I want to do then is to bind the keyup event on 'input'. However I want the event to reference the instance method contained in my function - this.KeyUpHandler().

Also I need 'e' to be event that would have been passed into the function had I just done this on the markup for the input (onkeypress="keyuphandler();").

Any ideas how I can bind the event to the a function in the instance of the function I am working within?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function Finder(id) {
  this.id = id;
  this.input = $("#" + this.id + " :input[type='text']:first")[0];
  that=this;
  this.KeyUpHandler = function (e) { ..the event should trigger this.. }
  $(this.input).bind('keyup', this.KeyUpHandler);
}
```

It is important that you call `bind()` **after** defining the function!

Comment: This is heading in the right direction. However inside my KeyUpHandler function 'this' is now something Jquery knows about rather than it being a means for me to reference my member variables. So I get a undefined error in my function when I try to use this.input, to reference what I originally set it to.

Comment: To clarify the above, 'this' has been set by JQuery to the element that triggered the event. I have lost my reference to my member variable.

Comment: @RemotecUk: Edited my answer. Now try to use `that` instead of `this` inside the event handler. Does it work?

Comment: Works perfectly! I used var ref = this; (but its the same thing).

Answer (score 0):

```
  this.KeyUpHandler = function (e) { ..the event should trigger this.. } 
     $(this.input).bind('keyup', function(){
          this.KeyUpHandler(event);
         //more code can go here
      });
```

Comment: You don't pass through `e`. Additionally, this wrapper function doesn't look very aesthetic.

Comment: Yes. Every function that listens for an event gets additional information about the event in the first parameter (except in IE, they did it a little bit uglier). Normally, this parameter has the name `e`.

Comment: passing the event keyword should do it