# binding html events to an instance of a controller class _within_ the constructor

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry, probably bit of a noob JS question regarding binding handlers to instances.

I am creating a controller instance with some data that will subsequently be used to process incoming events (the actual use case is composing complex d3 handlers with varying ajax urls and into which I compose the function(s) doing the actual tree update).

RequireJS and jquery are involved, but I suspect my issue has more to do with my specific binding code.  I guess I could forego the use of 'this' since I have only one controller per page which can be a global.  But this feels like it should be doable, if only I knew how to.

This is how I bind the controller to its target, **from within the constructor** (doing it outside the constructor seems to work):

```
function BtnMgr(msg, tgt_id) {
    this.msg = msg;
    this.tgt_id = tgt_id;
    var selector = "#" + tgt_id;
    $(selector).on("click", this.handleClick);
}
```

**What is going wrong?**

When I click on the button, 'this', in the handleClick refers to the html button, not to the controller instance.

If I call the controller instance method directly, 'this' is correct.

I've tried call or creating a wrapper function, as suggested in

[How can I bind an event handler to an instance in JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117361/how-can-i-bind-an-event-handler-to-an-instance-in-jquery)

```
$(selector).click(function(e) { BtnMgr.prototype.handleClick.call(this, e); });
```

My button click keeps seeing 'this' as the button, not the controller:

**output**

```
global var controller:BtnMgr.I am a button
this:[object HTMLButtonElement],type:
e:[object Object],type:Object
BtnMgr.handleClick:this.msg:undefined
```

Simplified version:

**HTML**

page4.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page 4</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.15/require.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    requirejs.config({
        baseUrl: '.',
        paths: {
            "jquery": "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min"
        }
    });
    var controller;
    require(["main4"], function(BtnMgr) {
        controller = new BtnMgr("I am a button", "btn_click");
        //this simulated call works - 'this' refers to the BtnMgr instance
        controller.handleClick("dummy_btn");
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="btn_click">click me!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

RequireJS

**main4.js**

```
define(["jquery"], function($) {

    function BtnMgr(msg, tgt_id) {
        this.msg = msg;
        this.tgt_id = tgt_id;
        var selector = "#" + tgt_id;

        $(selector).on("click", this.handleClick);

    }

    BtnMgr.prototype.toString = function(){
        return "BtnMgr." + this.msg;
    };

    BtnMgr.prototype.handleClick = function(e) {
        //I want 'this' to refer to the BtnMgr instance
        //and e to the html element that got clicked...

        console.log("global var controller:" + controller);
        console.log("this:" +  this + ",type:" + this.constructor.name);
        console.log("e:" +  e + ",type:" + e.constructor.name);
        console.log("BtnMgr.handleClick:this.msg:" + this.msg);
    };

    //define is returning the constructor method for the object 
    return BtnMgr;

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve (nearly) what you want with :

```
$(selector).on("click", this.handleClick.bind(this));
```

`this` will be the instance of BtnMgr and `e.target` will, as always, be the button.

However, that would fly in the face of convention and confuse anyone trying to understand your code, including yourself in 6 months time. In a click handler, `this` should always refer to the clicked element, as is natural.

If you really must have a reference from the handler back to the instance of BtnMgr that attached the click, then I might opt for "e-augmentation" like this :

```
function BtnMgr(msg, tgt_id) {
    var that = this;
    this.msg = msg;
    this.tgt_id = tgt_id;
    var selector = "#" + tgt_id;
    $(selector).on("click", function(e) {
        e.clickAttacher = that;
        that.handleClick(e);
    });
}

BtnMgr.prototype.toString = function(){
    return "BtnMgr." + this.msg;
};

BtnMgr.prototype.handleClick = function(e) {
    console.log("click attacher was instance of : " + e.clickAttacher.constructor.name); // BtnMgr
    console.log("button id: " +  e.target.id); // xxx
    console.log("msg: " + e.clickAttacher.msg); // Hello World!
};

var b = new BtnMgr('Hello World!', 'xxx');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/knkhryp0/1/)**

Having done that, you have to ask whether it's really worthwhile defining `handleClick` in that way. Sure, if it's a monster function then yes, define it with `BtnMgr.prototype....`, but if it's only small, then define it in the constructor itself and take direct advantage of `that` being in the scope chain (as does the augmenter function above).

Comment: Dan and you both have the correct idea, which is to use $.proxy or bind to force what is going to end up in 'this'.  bind seems more built-into modern JS, so I'll pick it.  The reason I don't want to have 'this' refer to the button is that, in my real use, this is just an event to a manager object.  The manager has loaded a number of loose-coupling modules via requirejs: a generic d3 tree module with boilerplate stuff.  Different pages have different d3 modules to add nodes and ajax urls to call.  The manager, 'this', orchestrates all the processing so the event's origin doesn't matter much.

Answer (score 1):

Try this when you bind your onClick:

```
function BtnMgr(msg, tgt_id) {
    this.msg = msg;
    this.tgt_id = tgt_id;
    var selector = "#" + tgt_id;
    $(selector).on("click", $.proxy(this.handleClick, this));
}
```

That would make sure that the 'this' variable in your callback is your class and not the clickevent.
You can read more about jQuery Proxy here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/

Comment: Lemme check this out, but yes, I think proxy is what I want. I ran into another error of same type elsewhere - bad 'this'. Looking at "Speaking Javascript", the author says that you need to repeat the instance variable when you call method you've stored in a variable. I suspect $'s proxy does that, and more. On Python, once you store a reference to an instance method, it knows the instance from then on, so I assumed the same from JS.  Mind you, that took me looong time to figure out there too.

Comment: Yes, the proxy method creates a variable with 'this' and then calls apply on the method with the stored reference to 'this'. You can google "js apply" if  You want to read more about how it works.